# Auth::attempt always returns false — not selecting password

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When trying to use Laravel's Auth class, I see that it always fails because (AFAIK) the attempt() method is only trying to select the username:

```
string(55) "SELECT * FROM `mdl_user` WHERE (`username` = ?) LIMIT 1"
```

(That's outputted via Event::listen('laravel.eloquent'))

I'm using Eloquent as the driver, the table fields are 'username' and 'password', and my model (Moodle_User, located at models/moodle/user.php) is written like this:

```
class Moodle_User extends Eloquent {
    public static $table        = 'user';
    public static $connection   = 'moodle';
}
```

If I use the model as-is, it works flawlessly:

```
// returns the correct object
$user = Moodle_User::where('username', $username)->where('password', md5($password))->get();
```

Also, I'm not using the Hash class because Moodle currently uses MD5, so I call `Auth::attempt()` like this:

```
Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)))
```

But it always returns false. If I do the exact same thing via the Moodle_User model, it works as expected.

Why does it ALWAYS return false?

Comment: If you don't want to use Hash::make(), please create your own Auth driver and extends it. Eloquent Auth Driver is using Hash::check().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're suppose to use `Hash::make()` not `md5()` to hash your passwords.

http://laravel.asia/p/laravel-authentication

I'd suggest you use your own driver because `attempt` in the `eloquent` driver and `fluent` driver uses `Hash::check()`:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/auth/drivers/eloquent.php#L53

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/auth/drivers/fluent.php#L41

Comment: As I stated in my question, I'm not using `Hash::make()` because I'm connecting to an external database which uses MD5 for password hashing, so using bcrypt is not an option. Also, as [stated in the manual](http://laravel.com/docs/auth/usage#login), you don't need to hash the password to use `Auth::attempt()` (although reccomended).

Comment: did you set your username column to `username` instead of `email`?

Comment: Yup. `'username' => 'username'`, `'password' => 'password'` (the database columns are named like that), and I set the correct model (**Moodle_User**) in the config.php file. Also, I set the correct static variables inside the model. The model works, the auth doesn't.

Comment: I was checking Laravel's source code and I just found out about that. Thanks for pointing that out.